# c++ storing a value inside unsigned int with bitmanipulation

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Maybe there is an answer for this but i couldn't find one i understand, so forgive me.

Say you have a variable with an unsigned int (32-bits) *foo* which i want to use for storing values in. As an example i want to store the values 1 and 4 inside the unsigned int as flags which makes the corresponding binary places to 1. *foo* would then look like all zeros until the last eight bits where it would be 0001 0010 (where the rightmost 0 represents the value 0). How do i do this using bitmanipulation?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
unsigned int const flag_one  = 0x02;  // 0000 0010
unsigned int const flag_four = 0x10;  // 0001 0000

unsigned int myflag = flag_one | flag_four;

// to test:
if (myflag & flag_one) { /* flag one is set */ }

// to set:
your_flag |= flag_four;     //  ORs with 0001 0000

// to clear:
their_flag &= ~flag_four;   // ANDs with 1110 1111
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mark specific places, just use a bitshift. Here's a small example:

```
void setflag(int * flag, int place)
{
    // Or sets it to true if it's 0 or 1
    *flag |= (1 << place);
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int flag = 0;

    setflag(&flag, 1);
    setflag(&flag, 4);

    printf("Flag is now %d\n", flag);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Flag is now 18
```

18 in binary is 10010, so that meets you criteria.